# Generating the Indicator by removing Saturday's and Sunday's

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

```
Customer_Id     IEX_Type    Call_Date         Day_Name    Required_Output

074332          AFTW IMA    2019-08-02  Friday       1
074332          AFTW IMA    2019-08-03  Saturday     0
074332          AFTW IMA    2019-08-04  Sunday       0
074332          AFTW IMA    2019-08-05  Monday       0
074332          AFTW IMA    2019-08-06  Tuesday      0
074332          AFTW IMA    2019-08-07  Wednesday    0
074332          AFTW IMA    2019-08-08  Thursday     0 
074332          AFTW IMA    2019-08-12  Monday       1
074332          AFTW IMA    2019-08-13  Tuesday      0
074332          AFTW IMA    2019-08-14  Wednesday    0
074332          AFTW IMA    2019-08-22  Thursday     0
074332          AFTW IMA    2019-08-23  Friday       0
074332          AFTW IMA    2020-10-31  Saturday     0
074332          AFTW IMA    2020-11-01  Sunday       0
074332          AFTW IMA    2020-11-02  Monday       1
074332          AFTW IMA    2020-11-03  Tuesday      0
074332          AFTW IMA    2020-11-04  Wednesday    0
074332          AFTW IMA    2020-11-05  Thursday     0
074332          AFTW IMA    2020-11-06  Friday       0
```

For the above table I need to generate the indictors based on the customer_id and IEX_Type but the condition here is...the call_date is in between 5 days need to generate indicator as 1 for the first record and for the rest of records need to generate as 0 ... and one more main condition is.... we should not consider Saturday's & Sunday's in those 5 days...

I have tried recursive CTE and generated row numbers() but I am unable to remove the Saturday's & Sunday's in those 5 days.... Can any one please help me with an T-SQL Script.

Comment: *"I have tried recursive CTE and generated row numbers() but I am unable to remove the Saturday's & Sunday's in those 5 days."* You forgot to include that attempt in the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check if below works for you

```
;WITH 
cte_data AS (
    SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Call_Date ) rn
    FROM table_name 
    WHERE DATENAME(dw,Call_Date) not in ('saturday','sunday') 
)
, cte_data_excluded AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM table_name 
    WHERE DATENAME(dw,Call_Date)  in ('saturday','sunday') 
)

SELECT  Customer_Id,
        IEX_Type,
        Call_Date,
        Day_Name,
        CASE WHEN rn%5=1 
                THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END Required_Output
FROM cte_data
UNION ALL
SELECT Customer_Id,
        IEX_Type,
        Call_Date,
        Day_Name,
        0
FROM cte_data_excluded
ORDER BY 3
```